# Get Strings with or without apostrophe in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table `place` which contains name of places, some of these names have an apostrophe in it for example place called `OJ's`.

When someone write exactly the same word he get the place data but if he missed the apostrophe `'` he get's nothing.

Can anybody help me to write the correct `mysql` statement that let's me get the strings whether the user writes down the apostrophe or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try soundex .. this will ignore special characters

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE soundex(column)=soundex('input')
```

EXAMPLE

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `itemname` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `test`
--

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `itemname`) VALUES
(1, 'ab''s'),
(2, 'abs'),
(3, 'aa'),
(4, 'a''a'),
(5, 'C'),
(6, 'C');

SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE soundex(itemname)=soundex('abs')
```

will return

```
1|ab's

2|abs
```